# Can [a | b] expression be used in grep BRE mode?

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep

According to [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html), pipe line alternative is not supported in normal `grep` which is in BRE(basic regular expression) mode 
I have a simple text file:

```
cat file1.txt 
|||
This is new line
That is a new line2
```

But i using the following command do return something(don't know why)

```
grep "Th[is|at]" files/file1.txt
```

returns

```
This is new line
That is a new line2
```

which `Thi` and `Tha` is highlighted by zsh, so I think they are the part matched by grep, Can anybody explain this?

Comment: Your regex is looking for `Th` followed by any one character from a choice of five: `i`, `s`, `a`, `t`, or `|`.  It will select `Thin mints` and `Th|piped` and `Ths` and so on as well as `This` and `That`.  The highlighting is telling you what matched.  Inside a character class, most characters lose their special meaning (and `]` and `-` and in certain contexts, `:` gain meaning — think `[[:alpha:]]` etc.). Note that even in ERE or PCRE, `[is|at]` is a five-character character class; it needs parentheses to make it an alternation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with what you are doing:

- You seem to be confused about alternation and character classes.  Saying `[bar]` would match either `b` or `a` or `r`.  In order to match either `is` or `at`, you would say `(is|at)`.
- When using BRE, `(`, `)`, `|`, ... aren't special, you need to escape those.

Instead use:

```
grep "Th\(is\|at\)" filename
```

The same pattern in ERE would be written as:

```
grep -E "Th(is|at)" filename
```

You might also want to refer to [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: `\|` is a GNU extension to BRE , so the most portable would be to use ERE